# Issue in using setWebViewClient with CordovaWebView

Tags: android, cordova, cordovawebview

I need a small help in Phonegap application.

I am having one `CordovaWebView` in my application. I need to load a particular page from my html (which is having multiple pages as per jQuery Mobile page structure) in that, so I use `loadUrl` like this:

```
cWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html#some-page-id");
```

This works fine. I am able to see that `some-page-id`.

Now I need to add `WebViewClient` for `cWebView`. If I do that, I get the error and url is not loaded in the webview.

Code:

```
cWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCordovaWebViewClient(this, cWebView));

public class MyCordovaWebViewClient extends CordovaWebViewClient {

    public MyCordovaWebViewClient(CordovaInterface cordova,
            CordovaWebView view) {
        super(cordova, view);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "my page finished " + url);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Application Error: A network error occurred. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html#some-page-id)
```

If I just load index.html, without giving the specific page id, then I don't get any issue in `setWebViewClient`.

Any solution to use `setWebViewClient` with a specific page id?